# Spark 1.2 on AWS EMR with emr release > 5.00

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I use AWS EMR to run some java Spark application.

Is it possible to install Spark with version 1.2 as bootstrap action for emr release > 5.0?
When I trying to do is, I get error that such bootstrap action is not supported on my emr release.
I am not able to find any information regarding this in documentation

Comment: This is a very specific issue yet the question is quite broad. Spark 1.2 is almost 5 years old... There is lots of *aws* libraries that spark uses on EMR.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is old. As per some specific circumstances I am not able to update spark to newer version right now. Is that possible to run Spark 1.2 on emr version > 5 ?

Comment: Besides using what's described here https://github.com/aws-samples/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/README.md and hoping for the best. I don't see this working.